# Lines between the CheckBoxList items

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, checkboxlist

I am looking for a CSS code for a `CheckBoxList` to add lines between items.Can someone help me how to add the dividing lines between the items of a `CheckBoxList`?

Below is a sample image of the format I am looking.

[image]

And below is my `aspx` code for the `CheckBoxList`:

```
<td colspan="5" id="Field_Referral_Codes">
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"  BorderWidth="1" Width="330px" Height="150px" ScrollBars="Vertical">
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklistReferralCodes" runat="server">
  </asp:CheckBoxList>
 </asp:Panel>
  </td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just put it in a table? If that's out of the question, post your code so people can give you good feedback.

Comment: Hi i have added the asp.net code above.

Comment: You have to write CSS for this, Post your View source for checkbox list

Answer (score 0):

for adding lines between rows you can specify a `CssClass` for `CheckBoxList` items in code behind as this:

```
ListItem me = new ListItem("majid");
me.Attributes["class"] = "checks";
chklistReferralCodes.Items.Add(me);
```

and then in CSS:

```
.checks 
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
}
```